# Python file access by user input

Tags: python, file

Here is a function in my code, I have a previously written file called numbers.txt . I am trying to read that file should they enter numbers or numbers.txt. However, it prints the file no matter what input is entered.

```
userfile = input('Please enter file name: ')
if userfile == 'numbers' or 'numbers.txt':
    f = open('numbers.txt','r')
    for line in f:
       print(line)
else:
    print('Sorry, this file does not exist')
```

Comment: `if userfile=='numbers' or userfile=='numbers.txt':`

Comment: Or `if userfile in ('numbers', 'numbers.txt'):`

Comment: try `if userfile=='numbers' or userfile=='numbers.txt':`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
if userfile=='numbers' or 'numbers.txt':  # After the or
```

In python a string is True if it's not empty ('') so 'numbers.txt' is True.
Change it to :

```
if userfile == 'numbers' or userfile == 'numbers.txt':
```

Answer (score 0):

```
userfile=input('Please enter file name: ')
if (userfile=='numbers') or (userfile=='numbers.txt'):
    try:
        f=open('numbers.txt','r')
    except:
        print('Sorry, this file does not exist')
        exit()
    for line in f:
       print(line)
else:
    print('Sorry, this file does not exist')
```